# Redirect from ip to domain

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I want to prevent site to be accessible by ip. It could be accessible by only domain name, so I tried with htaccess trick.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It did the trick now my siteurl is changed to mydomain.com instead of my ip. But as per my knowledge its not complete solution. Whenever I change permalinks new htaccess will be generated so above condition will be removed.

So I thought I have to try in index.php, tried to redirect if ip is there in url by following:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'111.111.111.11') !== false) {      
header("Location: mydomain.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

but it did nothing still site accessed by ip. Let me know if my approach is right or not. Suggest me anything else if there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress does not create a complete new .htaccess. It just rebuilds the part between the WordPress markers:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any rule placed outside of this block will not be touched.